# Is smiling instead of laughing a sin?

Tags: sin

Assalam Alaikum, brothers and sisters! Here's the situation: I was watching a video on how to do namaz correctly. In the video, the Sheikh was explaining how to lift his finger during namaz and his finger movements made me laugh a little, but I didn't laugh, I just smiled. Is my smile a mockery of religion or not? Is it a sin that I smiled at it or not? I am very worried about this.

Answer (score 0):

In the name of Allah, and All praises be to Allah the almighty.

In the permission of Allah, I will try to answer your question using a hadith.

In Saheeh Al Bukhari 1 [[Source](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1)]

"The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended"

End Quote

So, if you intention was to mock then Allah knows your intention, and if it was not then Allah knows your intention. Allah the almighty is the All-Knowing. He knows your intentions and knows every single thing. He is the All-Knowing.

I hope this answered your question, May Allah guide you, and those around you.

In the end, Allah knows best.